# I need to create a oracle table1 from another table2 in oracle. where i need to insert the data as the column name of table2. example

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

Example:

Table2 (original table)

```
custid   01-jan-2018   07-jan-2018  14-jan-2018  21-jan-2018
102      7               2            5            4
```

Need to create a table like below (Table1):

```
custid   date             data
102      01-jan-2018       7
102      07-jan-2018       2
102      14-jan-2018       5
102      21-jan-2018       4
```

Please advise how can I achieve/create table1 from table2.

Comment: Is the column creation in original table having some logic ? Eg Weekly ? Is it hard-coded to be like in your example or the solution has to be dynamic ? Eg. To work for feb,march etc. as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are steps to achieve this scenario:

```
create table Table2
(custid number,
"01-jan-2018" number,
"07-jan-2018" number,
"14-jan-2018" number,
"21-jan-2018" number);

insert into Table2 values (102,7,2,5,4);

create table Table3
(custid number,
"date" date,
"data" number);

insert into Table3(custid,"date","data")  
(SELECT *
FROM Table2
UNPIVOT
INCLUDE NULLS
(DATA FOR COL IN
   (
     "01-jan-2018" ,"07-jan-2018","14-jan-2018","21-jan-2018"
   ) 
));

select * from table3;

102 01-JAN-18   7
102 07-JAN-18   2
102 14-JAN-18   5
102 21-JAN-18   4
```

Comment: while inserting the data in table3 (May be due to the date field is date and we are inserting the number data. error came--- ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Comment: may be you have number datatype ... I kept as date datatype for Table3 ... I did in Oracle 12c and I have no issues

Answer (score 0):

You may use `unpivot` keyword as :

```
create table Table1 as
with Table2(custid,d01_Jan_2018,d07_Jan_2018,d14_Jan_2018,d21_Jan_2018) as
(
 select  102, 7, 2, 5, 4 from dual   
)    
select custid, col1 as "DATE", data from Table2
unpivot 
(data for col1 in (d01_Jan_2018, d07_Jan_2018, d14_Jan_2018,d21_Jan_2018));

select * from Table1;

CUSTID      DATE       DATA
------  ------------   -----
 102    D01_JAN_2018     7
 102    D07_JAN_2018     2
 102    D14_JAN_2018     5
 102    D21_JAN_2018     4
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4194/67)

Comment: In table1 date column is real date column. I tried with same kid of your example.

Comment: @Virender what's `custid` then, a string type column wrapped in quotes as 'custid' ..?, I supposed that as a column name ...